# Replacing @Controller with @RestController in Spring Boot does not show intended view

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

While running tests against this controller, I get the Circular View Path error.  Replacing `@Controller` with `@RestController` fixes this error however now instead of the view showing in the browser I get the actual returned `String` in the view.

Example would be, when I replace `@Controller` below with `@RestController` and make a `GET` request mapping to `"/ListA"`, the controller method returns the String `ListA` in the browser as in all you see printed in the browser are the letters ListA and the view with all my inputs, buttons, tables do not show.

What am I missing here?

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping
 public class WebController {
    
      @GetMapping("/ListA") 
      public String viewListAController() {
          
          return "ListA";

      }

      @GetMapping("/ListB") 
      public String viewListBController() {
          
          return "ListB";

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RestController simplifies the creation of RESTful web services. It's a convenience annotation that combines @Controller and @ResponseBody.

if you use it it will convert the response into a JSON object format. That's why you are
getting a string as text in the browser, not the view.

Comment: Ok, just realized I totally should be using `@RestController` on the service app only and not this I app I am referring to which is the client.  I did not mention this was the client side. My bad. `@Controller` for Web & `@RestController` for service if I got that right. With the help of a coworker, I kept the `@Controller` and made the `@GetMapping` String different than the return String and all appears to be working.  With the help of the above answer I realized I was going down the wrong path.

Comment: enjoy..!! happy coding.